# Como integrar ASP.NET MVC Core com Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

Possuo um projeto que requer que o lado cliente utilize o Vue.js para renderização das views da aplicação, mas no lado servidor pretende-se utilizar o ASP.NET MVC Core para validar todas as regras de negócio.

Existe alguma forma de integrar ambas tecnologias?

Comment: Esse link pode te ajudar: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/14/running-vuejs-on-aspnet-core-apps/

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples e menos "dolosa" é passar o JSON do objeto para a view.

por exemplo:

```
<script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#clienteForm',
            data:  @Json.Serialize(Model)
        })
</script>
```

Agora o seu objeto `Vue` possui todos os dados do modelo

A outra opção é fazer o seu vue fazer requisições ajax para uma WebAPI que retorna os JSONs referentes aos objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, uma forma seria utilizar o asp.net core para servir como uma rest api, e utilizar a vuejs somente pra uma front end, na minha opinião é a melhor forma.